# How to create a data history in a dimension without using slowly changing dimension?

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, fact

I'm working on my fact table and I want to create history table for each dimension without using slowly changing dimension because my data flows are bulky and it will take too much time to finish the process of feeding the fact table ? Generally, slowly changing dimension works with dataset having less than 1000 records.

Comment: You might want to rethink that number. I have seen many slowly changing dimensions which have tens of millions of rows (10,000,000+). Any mainstream DBMS - SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, etc. - is capable of managing this volume.

Comment: I meant with simple hardware resources, SCD can be a solution if the dataset is less than 1000 rows. In my case, I'm dealing with huge dataset, using SCD may not be performat in term of time.

Comment: Ok I understand. What are the limits of SCD so far?

Comment: @RonDunn can you please check with this article ? https://blogs.perficient.com/2011/01/07/alternative-to-the-ssis-slowly-changing-dimension-wizard/

Comment: What are you asking me to check, please, Amira? It appears to be promoting an SSIS component which no longer exists.

Comment: I asked some experts and the answer was the same : the Slowly Changing Dimension task in SSIS does not perform well with large datasets. I just want to have counterexample from your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve used SCDs with 100s of thousands of elements and even millions. You’ll need to optimise your table, create indexes, etc, but there’s no reason not to use them.

Comment: Can you please tell me more about table optimization?